# Unable to read XML in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

I am facing some issue while validating XML in VBScript :-

This is my XML data. It contain number of `<item>` nodes. I want to check, when `<PNAME>` node value start with "I", then its `<PTYP>` node value should start with "I" and same for `<PGROUP>` node value.

If node values not starting with "I" in node `<PTYP>` and `<PGROUP>` then script should through some message.

```
<item>
  <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE</PNAME>
  <PTYP>I</PTYP>
  <PDESC>Order Number</PDESC>
  <PINDEX>0022</PINDEX>
  <PGROUP>I.01</PGROUP>
  <PREF_TYPE>DTEL</PREF_TYPE>
  <PREF_NAME>AUFNR</PREF_NAME>
  <PDOM>AUFNR</PDOM>
  <PDATTYP>CHAR</PDATTYP>
  <PDATLEN>0012</PDATLEN>
  <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
  <PINTLEN>000024</PINTLEN>
  <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
  <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
  <PREF_NAME2>AUFNR</PREF_NAME2>
  <VALUE>000500000020</VALUE>
  <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
 </item>
```

How should i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your data on a local xml file and the following seemed to work for me.  Hopefully this will help for you as well.  I did slightly modify the XML by adding a "items" element before the item as such.

```
<items>
 <item>
  <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE</PNAME>
  <PTYP>I</PTYP>
  <PDESC>Order Number</PDESC>
  <PINDEX>0022</PINDEX>
  <PGROUP>I.01</PGROUP>
  <PREF_TYPE>DTEL</PREF_TYPE>
  <PREF_NAME>AUFNR</PREF_NAME>
  <PDOM>AUFNR</PDOM>
  <PDATTYP>CHAR</PDATTYP>
  <PDATLEN>0012</PDATLEN>
  <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
  <PINTLEN>000024</PINTLEN>
  <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
  <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
  <PREF_NAME2>AUFNR</PREF_NAME2>
  <VALUE>000500000020</VALUE>
  <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
</item>
<item>
  <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE2</PNAME>
  <PTYP>B</PTYP>
  <PDESC>Order Number</PDESC>
  <PINDEX>0022</PINDEX>
  <PGROUP>I.01</PGROUP>
  <PREF_TYPE>DTEL</PREF_TYPE>
  <PREF_NAME>AUFNR</PREF_NAME>
  <PDOM>AUFNR</PDOM>
  <PDATTYP>CHAR</PDATTYP>
  <PDATLEN>0012</PDATLEN>
  <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
  <PINTLEN>000024</PINTLEN>
  <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
  <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
  <PREF_NAME2>AUFNR</PREF_NAME2>
  <VALUE>000500000020</VALUE>
  <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
 </item>
 <item>
  <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE3</PNAME>
  <PTYP>I</PTYP>
  <PDESC>Order Number</PDESC>
  <PINDEX>0022</PINDEX>
  <PGROUP>I.01</PGROUP>
  <PREF_TYPE>DTEL</PREF_TYPE>
  <PREF_NAME>AUFNR</PREF_NAME>
  <PDOM>AUFNR</PDOM>
  <PDATTYP>CHAR</PDATTYP>
  <PDATLEN>0012</PDATLEN>
  <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
  <PINTLEN>000024</PINTLEN>
  <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
  <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
  <PREF_NAME2>AUFNR</PREF_NAME2>
  <VALUE>000500000020</VALUE>
  <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
</item>
<item>
  <PNAME>I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE4</PNAME>
  <PTYP>I</PTYP>
  <PDESC>Order Number</PDESC>
  <PINDEX>0022</PINDEX>
  <PGROUP>B.01</PGROUP>
  <PREF_TYPE>DTEL</PREF_TYPE>
  <PREF_NAME>AUFNR</PREF_NAME>
  <PDOM>AUFNR</PDOM>
  <PDATTYP>CHAR</PDATTYP>
  <PDATLEN>0012</PDATLEN>
  <PINTTYP>C</PINTTYP>
  <PINTLEN>000024</PINTLEN>
  <PDECIMALS>000000</PDECIMALS>
  <SORT_LNR>0001</SORT_LNR>
  <PREF_NAME2>AUFNR</PREF_NAME2>
  <VALUE>000500000020</VALUE>
  <TAB_INDEX>0</TAB_INDEX>
  </item>
 </items>
```

Script:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("items.xml")

Set root = xmlDoc.documentElement
Set items = root.childNodes

for each item in items

    myPNAME = item.getElementsByTagName("PNAME").item(0).text
    myPTYP = item.getElementsByTagName("PTYP").item(0).text
    myPGROUP = item.getElementsByTagName("PGROUP").item(0).text

    If Left(myPNAME, 1) = "I" Then
        'myPNAME Starts with "I"

        IsValid = True
        'Innocent until proven guilty

        If Left(myPTYP, 1) <> "I" Then

            IsValid = False

        End If

        If Left(myPGROUP, 1) <> "I" Then

            IsValid = False

        End If

        If IsValid = False Then

            wscript.echo myPNAME & " is not valid."

        End If

        IsValid = True

    End If

next
```

Output

`I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE2 is invalid`

`I_ORDER_NUMBER_FROM_TABLE4 is invalid`

Comment: I have executed above code but I'm getting error like "Object required : 'root' at this line "Set items = root.childNodes "plz help me on this

Comment: When you said that you had a number of "item" nodes, I thought that it was because the "item" nodes were in cased inside of an "items" node.  Hopefully you can modify your xml doc so that you can have add this items node to the beginning and end of your xml document.  I will post the actual data that I used.

Comment: I am curious, was this helpful?